# ggplot2 How to move legend, and how to fill and dodge on multiple variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, fill

Question 1: Is it possible to have ggplot fill by one variable, and dodge by another variable? 
  In this example group I would like to group Claims within Categories?
  I have researched this site and tried playing around code by manipulating the variables used in the aes () code as well as the variables in the fill and dodge but to no avail. (Additional note, following a constructive comment on this: if you are not aware of a ggplot way to do this but would like recommend another graphics package you know can do this, I would be interested in the referral)

Question 2: What is the code to move the legend to the top of the graph. 
I know this must seem basic to some, but I have read many similar questions and the answers often seem out of date referring to the opts() function
I have also tried using the theme and guides code written as comments below

```
df<-data.frame (Categories=c("Alpha Category", "Alpha Category",  "Alpha Category", "Alpha Category", "Bravo Category",  "Bravo Category", "Bravo Category", "Charlie Category" ,  "Charlie Category", "Charlie Category"),  Claim=c("claim1", "claim2", "claim3", "claim4", "claim5", "claim6", "claim7", "claim8","claim9", "claim10")  , Strong.Agreement=c(66,57,59,84,77,78,54,53,70,67), Somewhat.Agreement=c(18, 32, 35, 13, 22, 18, 36, 38, 27, 32) )
df$Claim <- reorder(df$Claim,df$Strong.Agreement)      
df.melt = melt(df, id.vars=c("Categories", "Claim"), measure.vars=c("Strong.Agreement","Somewhat.Agreement"), variable.name="Agreement", value.name="Ratings")  # Melt the data frame   
agreement.plot <- ggplot(df.melt, aes(x = Claim, y = Ratings, fill = Agreement)) +              
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + coord_flip()+
 theme_classic(base_size = 15, base_family = "") + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")
 #+ theme(legend.position = "top")
  #guides(colour = guide_legend(title.position = "top"))
agreement.plot
```

Comment: This is a valuable link: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/ in helping to understanding ggplot2.

Comment: Definite thanks for the reminder, it's a great site.  I realize now my problem with legend was syntax and I will read more about facet_grid there.

Comment: Questoin 1: I believe it's impossible with ggplot to fill (and position) by one variable, and then group and position (dfferently) by another. Logically it makes complete sense but probably beyond current barplot capability.

Answer (score 2):

This would be my approach:

```
ggplot(df.melt, aes(x = Claim, y = Ratings, fill = Agreement)) +              
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + coord_flip()+
    theme_classic(base_size = 15, base_family = "") + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") +
    theme(legend.position="top") +
    facet_grid(Categories~.)
```

I use `facet_grid` instead of the dodge and fill.  Not sure how to do both dodge and fill or if it's possible.

Comment: oh, i think my problem with theme(legend.position="top") was where I put the + sign.  I'll never make that mistake again.  I will have to read more about facet_grid.  I wonder if there is a way we can suppress the (Claims) items that don't fall into the other Categories

Comment: Not currently.  The `coord_flip` doesn't like `scales = "free"` currently.